# How do you enable BuildKit with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-buildkit

I tried `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` before a `docker-compose build` command and I did not see the expected BuildKit output. What did I miss?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Support for BuildKit was just released in [docker-compose 1.25.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.0). To enable:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 # or configure in daemon.json
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
```

With those variables set in your shell, you can now run `docker-compose build` using BuildKit.

In windows you can execute in your console:

```
setx DOCKER_BUILDKIT 1 # or configure in daemon.json
setx COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD 1
```

after will need restart your console

Comment: Is this still the right answer? How does this play with `docker compose` vs `docker-compose`?

Comment: This does not work when using sudo. How can I set COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD globally instead of an environment variable?

Comment: @AndyRay iirc, `docker compose`(without the hyphen) is a sort of a plugin that docker made to tackle "how to deploy structure prepped by docker-compose file on AWS's ECS", as opposed to Amazon's take on that is "docker-compose is an implementation detail for development environment, which we are not going to cater to. We have ECS CLI (or better yet, the latest Copilot)".

Comment: This is very inconvenient, it's a pity that we can't manage it via yml file

Answer (score 33):

You can use this command to tell **docker-compose** to use the **Docker CLI** when executing a build.

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 docker-compose build
```

You should see the same build as usual, but with this warning:

> WARNING: Native build is an experimental feature and could change at
> any time

And you can go like that to parametrize the CLI to use **BuildKit** instead of the default builder:

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build
```

Windows version:

```
set "COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1" & set "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1" & docker-compose build
```

You can also enable **BuildKit** globally, editing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, adding:

```
{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }
```

For more informations: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Answer (score 8):

Docker Compose v2 supports BuildKit by default: [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-upgrade-to-docker-compose-v2/)

> While most migrations should be straightforward, Compose v2 does introduce a few breaking changes which could impact specific use cases:
>
> - Containers are now created with hyphens in their names instead of underscores.
> - **`docker compose build` builds with BuildKit by default.**
> - Some deprecated command flags have been removed.